# Proving $-(-z) = z$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I've managed to prove this:

$$0 = (-1+1)z = -1\cdot z + z \rightarrow $$

$$-1\cdot z = -z$$

but how to prove that $-(-z) = z$?

Comment: Try it with $-z$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since $z+(-z)=0$ then the additive inverse of $-z$ must be $z$. But $-(-z)$ is, by definition, the inverse of $-z$, so $-(-z)=z$.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the associative law for multiplication on the LHS of −(−z)=z−(−z)=z to get:

−(−z) = (-1 $\cdot$ -1) $\cdot$ z
      = 1 $\cdot$ z
      = z
and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

In order for:$-(-z)=z$ to be true, i think that we can prove it like that:
$$
-z-(-z)=0\\
(-1)⋅z + (-1)⋅(-z) = 0\\
(-1)⋅(z-z) = 0 \\
z-z = 0 \\
z = z \\
$$
Since z it's obvious equals z, the first statement: $-(-z)=z$ is true, because all we've done is manipulated it algebraically